# How read oracle output array parameter c#

Tags: c#, oracle

Hi i have this procedure:

```
DECLARE 
 I_BIG_INSTITUTION_CODE VARCHAR2(10);
 I_BIG_ACTION_CODE VARCHAR2(10);
 O_CASES_TAB MY_API.VARCHAR_TAB;
 I_USER VARCHAR2(200);
 I_AD_USER VARCHAR2(200);
 I_LANGUAGE VARCHAR2(200);
 I_ASYS_ID NUMBER;
 O_RESULT_SUCCESSFUL BINARY_INTEGER;
 O_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
 I_BIG_INSTITUTION_CODE := 'KRD';
 I_BIG_ACTION_CODE := 'ADD';
 I_USER := 'User User';
 I_AD_USER := 'u.user';
 I_LANGUAGE := 'PL';
 I_ASYS_ID := 100;
 MY_API.PACKAGE_NAME.GET_PACK_TO_SEND(
 I_BIG_INSTITUTION_CODE => I_BIG_INSTITUTION_CODE,
 I_BIG_ACTION_CODE => I_BIG_ACTION_CODE,
 O_CASES_TAB => O_CASES_TAB,
 I_USER => I_USER,
 I_AD_USER => I_AD_USER,
 I_LANGUAGE => I_LANGUAGE,
 I_ASYS_ID => I_ASYS_ID,
 O_RESULT_SUCCESSFUL => O_RESULT_SUCCESSFUL,
 O_MESSAGE => O_MESSAGE);
  if O_CASES_TAB.count>0 then
   for i in  O_CASES_TAB.first..O_CASES_TAB.last loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_CASES_TAB = ' || O_CASES_TAB(i));
   end loop;
  end if;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_RESULT_SUCCESSFUL = ' || O_RESULT_SUCCESSFUL);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_MESSAGE = ' || O_MESSAGE);
END;
```

The procedure returns something like that:
[Procedure result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn49L.png)

Now I need to read the **o_cases_tab** parameter in C#, but I do not know how to do it. Here is the code that tries to do this:

```
public void GetPackToSend()
    {
        using (var connection = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "MY_API.PACKAGE_NAME.GET_PACK_TO_SEND";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("input_parameter1", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = "value_1" ;
                command.Parameters.Add("input_parameter2", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = "value_2";
                AddOutArrayParameter(command, "o_cases_tab", "MY_API.VARCHAR_TAB", 10);
                command.Parameters.AddRange(OracleParameterHelper.GetDefaultInputParameters()
                    .ToArray());
                command.Parameters.AddRange(OracleParameterHelper.GetDefaultOutputParameters().ToArray());

                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    var dbResult = new Tuple<string, string, object>(
                        command.Parameters["o_result_successful"].Value.ToString(),
                        command.Parameters["o_message"].Value.ToString(),
                        command.Parameters["o_cases_tab"].Value);
                }
                catch (OracleException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

**dbResult={(1, null, System.Object[])}** So in the parameter **o_cases_tab** I have : **System.Object[]**

Method addOutArrayParameter

```
private static void AddOutArrayParameter(OracleCommand command, string paramName,
        string paramTypeName, int size = 1)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.Size = size;
        parameter.ArrayBindSize = size;
        parameter.UdtTypeName = paramTypeName;
        parameter.ParameterName = paramName;
        parameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
```

I'm definitely making a stupid mistake, but for the first time I'm working with oracle, so I'm asking for indulgence.

Comment: What is the problem? You already read the parameter value, it's the object array. If you know the actual type of the array's elements you can cast them, eg with `(string)thatArray[1]` or with the `Cast<String>()` LINQ method.

Comment: I can't cast elements because I have something like that: [link](https://prnt.sc/lxcyrn).

Comment: Post that in the *question*. That screenshots says nothing about casting though. It says the `lol` variable contains an empty array. If that variable contains the contents of the `o_cases_tab` parameter it means no results were returned. Either the stored procedure didn't return anything, or the parameter wasn't defined as `Output`